Accessing Kafka Headers when ingesting message with promtail
I am currently trying to ingest Kafka Messages on certain topics to loki using promtail.
So far, everything seems to work out.
But I do also need some of the Kafka Message Headers as labels in loki.
I have not found a way to access the headers with promtail and use them as labels, is there any way to do so?

You can set scrape_configs in promtail to add custom labels.
